# Jquery each function Index with radio group

Tags: jquery, sqlite, radio-button, each

I have a series of radio buttons which are created from an sqlite database

I am using the jquery each function to loop through the radio groups. For each group, if there is a checked item, I am inserting a record to the database as follows-

```
$('input:radio:checked').each(function(Index) {
Index=Index+1; // to start at 1 not 0

var kind_id = $('input:radio[name='+Index+']:checked').val(); 
// get value of the checked radio button  which corresponds to 'kind' index in the database

var cat_id = $('input[name='+Index+']:radio:checked').attr('data-id'); 
// get the radio group name which corresponds to the category index in the database and, in turn, is the value of Index

tx.executeSql( 'INSERT INTO quotelink(ql_quote_id,ql_cat_id,ql_kind_id) Values (last_insert_rowid(),?,?)', [cat_id,kind_id], 
nullHandler,errorHandler , 
[],nullHandler,errorHandler);
}); //end each function
```

This works fine until I delete a category. If, for example, I have categories 1,3,4,5 (I've deleted 2) in the database. When I trigger the function, I get four rows inserted, as expected, but the cat_id columns  are 1,undefined, 3, 4  - not 1,3,4,5.

i.e when Index=2 it's looking for an element that doesn't exist. I'm stuck as to what to do next.

Bit complicated - hope I've explained it ok, any help very much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "undefined" value is right, cause your trying to access a radio-input which does not exsits, so jquery/js will return "undefined".

I'll think it won't work with incrementing a index var in your loop.
Why don't you use the $(this) Object inside your loop to access the needed attributes of the current checked radio-input?

Try this:

```
$('input:radio:checked').each(function(Index) {

  //Index=Index+1; // to start at 1 not 0
  var currentRadio = $(this);

  //var kind_id = $('input:radio[name='+Index+']:checked').val(); 

  var kind_id = currentRadio.val();

  // get value of the checked radio button  which corresponds to 'kind' 
  // index in the database


  //var cat_id = $('input[name='+Index+']:radio:checked').attr('data-id'); 

  var cat_id = currentRadio.attr('data-id');

  // get the radio group name which corresponds to the category index in the database
  // and, //in turn, is the value of Index

  //... insert into database 
}
```